# How do I get MS-Access to show the Value for Grouping in my Report instead of only the indexing ID number(s)?

Tags: windows, microsoft-access

Well...I'm perplexed. I'm pretty new to Access, so I'm not terribly surprised when even simple things escape me.

I've created a dB for Safety Data Sheets where I work (thanks, OSHA, for job security).

The Report in question has an AreasUsedT table and a ChemicalsT table; I want to group my Report of Chemicals grouped by which Areas Used.
My Report does show this, **but** instead of listing the *Areas* where the group of Chemicals is used, it lists the *index*(?) *number(s)*.

I tried using the drop down & the expression builder for Control Source within the Property Sheet, but either method gives same result.

In the Group, Sort, and Total section at the bottom, it says the report's "Group on **AreaStored.Value**"

In the Property Sheet, it states Control Source is "AreaStored".

Does it matter that there's one-to-many relationships between Chemicals and Areas Used?

I've read MS's article about this without much help:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-grouped-or-summary-report-f23301a1-3e0a-4243-9002-4a23ac0fdbf3#__add_or_modify

(...and other googling I'm a poor historian of...)

illustration of grouping issue [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXeLd.jpg